# SQL Case always going to default and returning multiple results

Tags: sql-server-2014

The code below always returns the default case and the default returns many rows instead of just a single row.

I can't find a flaw in the logic but clearly, there is. The value I set the @id to is something I know is in my table as I copy pasted it directly from the table.

I'm aware the TOP 1 select isn't the best practice but it's what I was told to use.

```
DECLARE @Id varchar(50) = 'ThisUser';

SELECT
  CASE WHEN Tbl2._Id =  @Id
  THEN UPPER(Tbl2.Status)
  WHEN
    TBL2.foo = (SELECT TOP 1 Tbl1.bar FROM dbo.Table_1 AS Tbl1 WHERE _Id = @Id)
  THEN UPPER(Tbl2.Status)

  ELSE 'DENY'
END AS _Status
From dbo.Table_1 AS Tbl1, dbo.Table_2 AS tbl2
```

Comment: Can you give us the table definition for `Table_1` and `Table_2` ? The column types may impact the query

Comment: Also, why you select from `Table_1` if you never use it in the SELECT statement ?